# Condição IF codeigniter - Verificar se dado existe no banco de dados(model)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu tenho o seguinte método para obter dados no codeigniter.

```
// Obter Fase
public function obter_fase($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_empresa_fase);
    $this->db->select("tbl_empresa_fase.*, IF(tbl_empresa_fase.crud = 'C', 'R', 'C') as crud", FALSE);
    if (is_array($id))
    {
        $this->db->where_in('campanha_id',$id);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('campanha_id',$id);
    }
    $this->db->order_by('campanha_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $item = $query->result_array();
    return $item;
}
```

Funciona, mas caso o ID que está sendo procurado não existe no banco de dados, é retornado um erro e com o método acima, isto já é esperado.

Por este motivo, eu quero saber se há possibilidade de criar uma condição que verifica se o ID procurado existe no banco de dados.

Caso sim, retorna o `result_array`, caso não, retorna `return []`.

Comment: Antes do `return` oq eu há em `$item` quando o `$id` não existe?

Comment: Se não existe da erro..

Comment: Qual erro, qual linha?

Comment: Vou tentar a sua resposta, mas veja o erro:: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY `campanha_id`' at line 3

SELECT tbl_empresa_fase.*, IF(tbl_empresa_fase.crud = 'C', 'R', 'C') as crud FROM `tbl_empresa_fase` WHERE campanha_id IN() ORDER BY `campanha_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente verificar a variável `$item` antes na hora de retornar o valor da função

```
//retornando com um if
if ($item) {
     return $item;
} else {
     return [];
}

//retornando com um ternário
return empty($item) ? [] : $item;
```

Pelo que vi na mensagem de erro o *select* etá vazio dentro do `IN()`, então essa mesma verificação pode ser realizada antes da *query*

```
// Obter Fase
public function obter_fase($id)
{
    if(empty($id) && is_numeric($id)) return []; // aqui verifica se o id passado é um número e se há valor
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_empresa_fase);
    $this->db->select("tbl_empresa_fase.*, IF(tbl_empresa_fase.crud = 'C', 'R', 'C') as crud", FALSE);
    if (is_array($id)) {
        $this->db->where_in('campanha_id',$id);
    } else {
        $this->db->where('campanha_id',$id);
    }
    $this->db->order_by('campanha_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $item = $query->result_array();
    return empty($item) ? [] : $item;
}
```

Comment: Com este eu ainda tenho este erro: SELECT tbl_empresa_fase.*, IF(tbl_empresa_fase.crud = 'C', 'R', 'C') as crud FROM `tbl_empresa_fase` WHERE campanha_id IN() ORDER BY `campanha_id`

Comment: Message: Call to undefined function is_number()

Comment: Tirei os `is_number` e funcionou...

Comment: Errei o nome da função, é `id_numeric()`, hehe